# Lightswitch, adding filter to query that relies on unsaved changes

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-lightswitch

I'm using Lightswitch and I'm trying to populate a dropdown list by filtering the query to the a list of items that have not been selected already.

The code I wrote works, but it is only using the data that has been "saved".  I'd like to filter out things that have been added, but not necessarily saved.

```
partial void NotAssignedToEventEmployee_PreprocessQuery(int? SelectedEventId, ref IQueryable<EmployeeItem> query)
{
    query = from a in query
            where a.AssignmentsAsEmployeeCollection.All(y => y.EventSetItem.Id != (int)SelectedEventId)
            select a;
}
```

Comment: is the unsaved data on the same screen? (or where is the unsaved data?)

Comment: On the same screen.  Basically I am trying to write a query to fill a drop down list, and when people select someone from the drop downlist, remove it from the list of available options

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of what the screen looks like? Is this only one dropdown box PER SCREEN or is it similar to a DataGrid with many rows and a dropdown box PER ROW? In any event, your best bet may be to create a [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) which tracks which Employees have been selected. OnScreenLoad or OnRowLoad: `query = from a in query where (hashset.Contains(a) == false) select a;` OnSave: hashset.Clear();

Comment: @jberger Yes, it is a dropdown list of choices for a field in a row of a datagrid.  I will try creating a new list (or hashset) and maintaining it seperately on the client side and let you know!  Thanks